# Perforce Connection.Connect FailFast Error

Tags: c#, perforce

Using the .net P4 api and encountering a strange error. I am creating a P4 client using a p4.ini file that looks to be correct with a valid client and server port. Calling into this client's Connection.Connect(new Options()), to reset the connection for separate reasons, ends up failing and fails by calling into FailFast which leaves me with no good debugging logs. I'm not sure what is failing here, since the client/p4.ini look just fine and this only comes up with using the Connection.Connect.

How can I either catch the error that is causing this behavior, or resolve the error?

at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
at System.Windows.Documents.MoveSizeWinEventHandler.WinEventProc(Int32, IntPtr)
at Perforce.P4.P4Bridge.ConnectA(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, LogMessageDelegate)
at Perforce.P4.P4Bridge.ConnectA(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, LogMessageDelegate)
at Perforce.P4.P4Server..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
at Perforce.P4.P4Server..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)
at Perforce.P4.Connection.Connect(Perforce.P4.Options)

Answer (score 0):

If the C# API works the same way as the C++ API, you'll want to `Final()` the connection before attempting to reopen it with `Connect()`.

Comment: I'm attempting to test this, but it will be a few hours before the bits get out. My understanding was that p4's c# api should be cleanly handling this though.

Comment: Disconnecting did not end up resolving the problem :(